# Replacing series data set is causing some series to be shifted along the x-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I have a line chart consisting of 8 series, the data for these series change depending on selections made on the page, but it always has the same number of data points (12).

I'm having a very strange issue where updating the data sets in my series array is cause 2 out of 8 lines to be shifted along the x-axis, depending on the number of times I change the data.

- Initially the chart is displayed correctly, with all lines starting in apr,
- then changing my selection once has 2 of the lines shifted right along the x-axis
- 2nd change
- then back to the initial selection

I've tried to illustrate the bug [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fGcz.jpg)

I couldn't reproduce the issues in jsfiddle, but the basic code of the chart is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clarelam/hy34to43/).
To update the data I pass a reference to the graph to my function:

```
function updateGraph(graph, data, driverData) {
  graph.title.text = data.description;

  graph.series[0].data = _.get(data, 'actual');
  graph.series[1].data = _.get(data, 'budget');
  graph.series[2].data = _.get(data, 'forecast');
  graph.series[3].data = _.get(data, 'forecast2');
  graph.series[4].data = _.get(data, 'py');

  graph.series[5].data = _.get(driverData, 'actual');
  graph.series[6].data = _.get(driverData, 'budget');
  graph.series[7].data = _.get(driverData, 'py');
}
```

Why am I seeing some of the lines being shifted along the x-axis? I have checked that the arrays all still contain 12 elements.

Thanks.

Comment: Here's a working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/nyhs26nw/, but the buttons clicks are not working - could you fix that? Anyway, Highcharts are altering data used for series, so you should be using copies of arrays and store the original data somewhere else - maybe this is the problem here?